# Drf docs is not running on my system

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Drf docs is not working. When I try to open it on local server http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/ it is redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/changecity/?Next/docs/

I cannot understand why. If you could please help.

Comment: add your urls, please

Comment: url(r'^admin/hub/', include('hub.adminurls')),
                                                                                                            url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
                                                                                                           url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_docs.urls')),

Comment: please, next time add you code to the question.